# why we get values in variable that are different

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, lsblk

when I want to get the size of sdb size on remote machine - master

I get that:

```
#  ssh master "lsblk | grep \"^sdb\" | awk '{print \$4}' "
100G
```

but

when we want to set the size value in variable and then to print it 
then we get that:

```
# VAR=` ssh master "lsblk | grep \"^sdb\" | awk '{print \$4}' " `
# echo $VAR
sdb 8:16 0 100G 0 disk
```

why the last test not give only the 100G size ?

what is the diff here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't run stuff remotely that you could run locally.

```
var=$( ssh master lsblk | awk '/^sdb/ { print $4 }' )
```

For when the value `sdb` is in a variable (from comments below):

```
var=$( ssh master lsblk | awk -v disk="$variable" '$0 ~ disk { print $4 }' )
```

or, to force a match at the start of the line,

```
var=$( ssh master lsblk | awk -v disk="$variable" '$0 ~ "^" disk { print $4 }' )
```

Comment: what in case we want to set sdb in variable ?

Comment: we try that , but not works var=$( ssh master02 lsblk | awk -v Disk=sdb '/^Disk/ { print $4 }' )

Comment: @yael See update

Answer (score 0):

need to add another back slash as:

```
VAR=` ssh master "lsblk | grep \"^sdb\" | awk '{print \\$4}' " `
echo $VAR
100G
```

Comment: You can also use `$(...)` instead of the old-style backquote form for command substitution. It changes the meaning of "\" before "$", "\`", or "\".